# How to extract / edit an attribute from a html tag using javascript or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Unless I did a mistake, I didn't find a clean/simple answer to my problem.

I have a  tags in a string and containing a src attribute :

```
var str = "<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" height="800" width="500"></iframe>"
```

Using JS or AngularJS (**ONLY !**) I want to extract somehow an attribute, for example `src` :

```
str.dosmthg("src","http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Output :

```
"<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/" height="800" width="500"></iframe>"
```

Same idea with `height` and `width`.

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: You can simply use javascript to achieve what you want. Using jquery it can be done very easily. Have a look at below link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: You could have separate variables in your controller if you are building it there anyways. Then just concatenate the variables as you build the element string. That way you have the height/width/etc vars later if you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a temp element and put your HTML into its `innerHTML`. Then you will be able to manipulate child nodes attributes.

```js
var tempEl = document.createElement('div');
tempEl.innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" height="800" width="500"></iframe>';
console.log(tempEl.childNodes[0].attributes['src'].value);
tempEl.childNodes[0].attributes['src'].value = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
console.log(tempEl.childNodes[0].attributes['src'].value);
console.log(tempEl.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the browser to parse the HTML, then read the attribute values from the resulting DOM element; see comments:

```js
// Your string
var str = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" height="800" width="500"></iframe>';

// Create an appropriate parent element for the string; note we don't
// actually attach this to the DOM anywhere
var body = document.createElement('body');

// Use the element to parse the HTML
body.innerHTML = str;

// Get the iframe from the element
var iframe = body.querySelector("iframe");

// Get the attributes from the element
console.log("src = ", iframe.getAttribute("src"));
console.log("height = ", iframe.getAttribute("height"));
console.log("width = ", iframe.getAttribute("width"));
```